# Error occurs on promise in node.js looking to make this a promised connection and fix

Tags: node.js, promise, mysql2

```
await conn.query("SELECT ID, idle_timer, action, combat FROM users WHERE idle_timer >= 1 ORDER BY ID ASC", async function(err, results) {
    }
```

error occurs at await conn.query("SELECT ID, idle_timer, action, combat FROM users WHERE idle_timer >= 1 ORDER BY ID ASC", async function(err, results) {

looking to convert this to a promise?

Comment: The error says it all. `conn.query(...)` is async and does not have a callback function. Either use `let [rows, fields]= await conn.query("select ...");` or `conn.query("select ...").then(data => { ....)` See also the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper)

Comment: `const results = await conn.query...` and remove the callback function and put that logic in the function itself.

Comment: I just started node development today, I really don't know what I'm doing besides scrapping things together from what I knew about js previously. Any way you could possibly give me an example of this converted to what you're suggesting? Sorry I know I sound overly stupid but I'm an example and implementation type of person lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MySQL for fetching data

in callback mode

```
conn.query("SELECT ID, idle_timer, action, combat FROM users WHERE idle_timer >= 1 ORDER BY ID ASC", function(err, results) {...})
```

or in the Promise mode

```
conn.query("SELECT ID, idle_timer, action, combat FROM users WHERE idle_timer >= 1 ORDER BY ID ASC").then(results => { ... })
```

or maybe in Promise mode with Await/Async syntax sugar

```
const result = await conn.query("SELECT ID, idle_timer, action, combat FROM users WHERE idle_timer >= 1 ORDER BY ID ASC")
```

```
    //...
    const results = await conn.query("SELECT ID, idle_timer, action, combat FROM users WHERE idle_timer >= 1 ORDER BY ID ASC");
    await conn.release();

    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        //... processing results
    }
```

if you new to async/await please read about promises, at least https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function